# Best way to sync files - copy only EXISTING files and only if NEWER than target

Tags: rsync, backup, file-copy, synchronization

I'm doing this sync locally on Ubuntu 12.04. The files are generally small text files (code).

I want to copy (preserving mtime stamp) from `source` directory to `target` but I only want to copy if the file in `target` **already exists** and is **older** than the one in `source`.

So I am only copying files that are newer in `source`, but they must exist in `target` or they won't be copied. (`source` will have many more files than `target`.)

I will actually be copying from `source` to multiple `target` directories. I mention this in case it impacts the choice of solution. However, I can easily run my command multiple times, specifying the new `target` each time, if that's what is required.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I believe you can use `rsync` to do this. The key observation would be in needing to use the `--existing` and `--update` switches.

```
        --existing              skip creating new files on receiver
        -u, --update            skip files that are newer on the receiver
```

A command like this would do it:

```
$ rsync -avz --update --existing src/ dst
```

#### Example

Say we have the following sample data.

```
$ mkdir -p src/; touch src/file{1..3}
$ mkdir -p dst/; touch dst/file{2..3}
$ touch -d 20120101 src/file2
```

Which looks as follows:

```
$ ls -l src/ dst/
dst/:
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 27 01:00 file2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 27 01:00 file3

src/:
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 27 01:00 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jan  1  2012 file2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 27 01:00 file3
```

Now if I were to sync these directories nothing would happen:

```
$ rsync -avz --update --existing src/ dst
sending incremental file list

sent 12 bytes  received 31 bytes  406.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

If we `touch` a source file so that it's newer:

```
$ touch src/file3 
$ ls -l src/file3
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 27 01:04 src/file3
```

Another run of the `rsync` command:

```
$ rsync -avz --update --existing src/ dst
sending incremental file list
file3

sent 115 bytes  received 31 bytes  292.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

We can see that `file3`, since it's newer, and that it exists in `dst/`, it gets sent.

#### Testing

To make sure things work before you cut the command loose, I'd suggest using another of `rsync`'s switches, `--dry-run`. Let's add another `-v` too so `rsync`'s output is more verbose.

```
$ rsync -avvz --dry-run --update --existing src/ dst 
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
file1
file2 is uptodate
file3 is newer
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 88 bytes  received 21 bytes  218.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't I need a few more rsync options? I'm reading the man page. Seems like I might need this: `rsync --archive --update --existing --whole-file --itemize-changes a/ b`. Or are most of those options unnecessary? (I added whole file because these are mostly small text files.)

Comment: @MountainX - only add options you need. I'd start with `-a` that's a superset of switches, `-rlptgoD`.

Comment: Let me clarify that. I'm confused about `--update` and `--existing`. Do I need both? I tested your solution and it seems to work, but I still feel safer adding `--update` .

Comment: @MountainX - sure you can add it in, I'll put it in the A too.